# Log viewer soft with a JSON presentation for windows

Tags: windows, json, log-analysis

I am looking for a software for watching changes on a file .
There are a lot of  softs for doing log survey  like mTail , but I did not found one that can display json on a beautiful way

Do you know a soft that would be a merge between mTail and JSON viewer please?